# Getting access to deep nested image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page which is set out thus:

```
<body>
<div class="header_div">
<object width="100%" height="30px" id="header" name="header" data="/cgi-bin/header.pl"></object>
</div>
<div class="page_div" id="page_div">
<object id="page" name="page" width="100%" height="100%" data="/cgi-bin/page.pl"></object>
</div>
<div class="menu_div" id="menu_div">
<object id="menu" data="/cgi-bin/menu.pl" width="250px" height="180px"></object>
</div>
<div class="login_div" id="login_div">
<object id="login" name="login" width="200px" height="300px" data="/cgi-bin/login.pl"></object>
</div>
```

Within the <object> tag of page is a script called "page.pl", (as shown). That calls another PERL script called "sidebar.pl" (effectively an INCLUDE tag) Within sidebar is a graphic called "login" (if the user clicks this, they can log in, and the form displays in "login div")

However, when results are displayed in "page.pl", there is a feature that needs the user to log in ... so "login div" is made visible again

The login details are now sent, and results returned to "login div", tag, together with a close window / (hide_div) option. Now, here comes the tricky bit! If poss, I want to change the "login" graphic in sidebar, (which is part of page div)

Due to the nesting structure, it would be difficult to go BACK to the graphic, so I'm thinking the easiest way to get to it is starting from the top of the browser (window.xxx ???)
The nested structure would be something like: "window.document.getElementById('page').getAttribute('data').innerHTML.getElementById('login').src" .. but that syntax is hopelessly wrong

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried "window.top" to get to the topmost frame and work down ... but that gave an "NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE"

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say, that I don't think you can parse the contents of something retrieved via an object tag. Instead, you should consider getting these elements via Ajax, and then you can parse their contents to your heart's content ;-)

Comment: Still experimenting. I have my javascript in a source file in root, and I have been able to 'sort of' get to part of the form; I've managed to retrieve "/cgi-bin/page.pl" with this:   function mask_login(){
var t=window.top.document.getElementById('page').getAttribute('data');
alert(t);
}  but of course, that's not the inherent HTML of the page

Comment: (Timed out on edits) You mention AJAX. (Only AJAX I know used to be a hoshold scouring powder!) So can you give any pointers?

Comment: After much experimenting, and reorganisation of divs, I have come up with two options. I can now access <object id="page" data="/cgi-bin/page.pl"></object> 1) I can get the object data source as "/cgi-bin/page.pl", but can't find a way to get the HTML code that the script returns to browser. The "innerHTML" tag shows what's between <object></object> so option 2) Load "page.pl" output into variable (XMLHTTP?) and put THAT between object tags. Lost as to how to do either!!